# message_filter (Python 3) not working in ROS Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python3, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**System information**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS version: Melodic
- Conda environment: python=3.7 (Needed for a python3 processing module)

**Problem explanation**

I try to create a message filter that subscribes to two `sensor_msg` topics after which a python3 module processes the Color and depth data in a callback function. To do this, I created the following script to achieve this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

## Import standard library packages ##
import sys

## Import ROS python packages ##
import rospy
import sensor_msgs
from message_filters import ApproximateTimeSynchronizer, Subscriber

def gotimage(image, camerainfo):
    assert image.header.stamp == camerainfo.header.stamp
    print("got an Image and CameraInfo")

## Main script ##
# Only runs when this script is executed directly
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ## Initialize ros node ##
    rospy.init_node('grasp_planner', anonymous=True)
    image_sub = Subscriber("/kinect2/hd/image_color", sensor_msgs.msg.Image)
    camera_sub = Subscriber("/kinect2/hd/camera_info", sensor_msgs.msg.CameraInfo)

    ## Create message_filter ##
    ats = ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, camera_sub], queue_size=5, slop=0.1)
    ats.registerCallback(gotimage)
    rospy.spin()
```

Unfortunately, after trying to run this script, I get the following error message:

```
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/ricks/miniconda3/envs/panda_autograsp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
[ERROR] [1566834367.342856]: bad callback: <bound method Subscriber.callback of <message_filters.Subscriber object at 0x7fb849e44f50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 75, in callback
    self.signalMessage(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 57, in signalMessage
    cb(*(msg + args))
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 282, in add
    for vv in itertools.product(*[zip(*s)[0] for s in stamps]):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/message_filters/__init__.py", line 282, in <listcomp>
    for vv in itertools.product(*[zip(*s)[0] for s in stamps]):
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable
```

Looks like the package released a [pull request](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1772) but it is not yet merged. In this, cause I'm unfortunately in a deadlock since my robot supports ROS up to version melodic and the image processing package is written in python3. Does anybody know what is the best way to solve my problem?

### What I already tried

- I tried setting the `export ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3` environmental variable.
- Building the [rospy](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/melodic-devel/clients/rospy) from source.

### Building rospy from source

1. Clone the rospy package into your `catkin_ws`.
2. Setting the `export ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3` environmental variable.
3. Building the rospy package using the `catkin_make -j4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DFranka_DIR:PATH="$HOME/libfranka/build" -Dfreenect2_DIR="$HOME/freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2"` command.
4. Source the `devel/setup.bash` file.

After these steps my python path becomes `PYTHONPATH=/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

When I try to run the python3 node I now get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/src/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 100, in load_command_line_node_params
    if rosgraph.names.is_legal_remap(arg):
AttributeError: module 'rosgraph.names' has no attribute 'is_legal_remap'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/src/panda_autograsp/nodes/grasp_planner_node.py", line 39, in <module>
    rospy.init_node('grasp_planner', anonymous=True)
  File "/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/src/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 326, in init_node
    _init_node_params(argv, name)
  File "/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/src/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 183, in _init_node_params
    params = load_command_line_node_params(argv)
  File "/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/src/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 107, in load_command_line_node_params
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("invalid command-line parameters: %s"%(str(e)))
rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: invalid command-line parameters: module 'rosgraph.names' has no attribute 'is_legal_remap'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331628/message_filter-(python-3)-not-working-in-ros-melodic/) by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:\

> Does anybody know what is the best way to solve my problem?

build `rospy` with the patch in your Catkin workspace (it wouldn't really be *building*, as `rospy` is all Python, but you'll need to do it anyway for Catkin to properly overlay the `apt` version with the version in your workspace)?

Btw: you appear to be mixing Python 2.x and Python 3 `PYTHONPATH`s. That is probably not a good idea.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-08-26**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks a lot for your answer. You mean that I have to build the `ros_comm` package (which includes the `rospy` module) from the source from within [my catkin workspace](https://github.com/rickstaa/panda_autograsp) as you explained in [#252478](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/) and [#295012](https://answers.ros.org/question/295012/how-can-i-install-ros-melodic-with-python3/)?

> Btw: you appear to be mixing Python 2.x and Python 3 PYTHONPATHs. That is probably not a good idea.

My PYTHONPATH currently is `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` since I sourced the `devel/setup.bash` of my workspace before running the python node. Do I need to remove this line when using a python3 ROS package?

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-08-26**:\

> Btw: you appear to be mixing Python 2.x and Python 3 PYTHONPATHs. That is probably not a good idea.

Ah, I now see what goes wrong. When I try to run the node in the python 3 virtual environment it gives me the  `No module named 'rospy' not found` error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:
You don't need to build all of `ros_comm` most likely. Copying out just the `rospy` client library package should be sufficient (not very maintainable, but it should work).

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-08-26**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for your explanation. I tried building the `rospy` module from source but I now get a new `attribute error`. The steps I performed while doing this can be found appended to the question above.

The other strange thing is that the python3 package still ends up in the `/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` folder instead of the `/home/ricks/panda_autograsp_ws/devel/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-27**:
I don't believe that is strange: from what you show here it would appear you're still mixing Python 2 and Python 3 (your Conda environment). Without special care, Catkin will use Python 2. `source`ing a workspace from inside your Conda environment will not change that.

Note that the patch only makes that particular part of `rospy` language-compatible with Python 3, if you're still using Python 2, Python 2 will still be used.

You may try the procedure outlined [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/?answer=331009#post-id-331009), but from within your Conda environment instead of a plain venv.

No guarantees, but it could work.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-08-29**:
@gvdhoorn thanks a lot for the explanation. I will do some testing and report my solution back as an answer.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2019-08-31**:
@gvdhoorn As I managed to use the package with python 2.7, after all, I didn't test the procedure you outlined in [this topic](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/?answer=331009#post-id-331009). I, however, added an answer based on my current findings below so I can close this question. Although I know I saw a python 3 transitioning status REP for the ROS main packages (see the  tag) somewhere I was unable to find it again. Do you maybe know where I can find such an overview? Feel free to correct me if I misunderstood something in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a package I was using recommended python3 I tried to get ROS to work with Python3. Below I summarised my findings while doing this.

#### Overal ROS python 3 support status

A list of ROS distributions and their python-support status can be found [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html). A guide on how to use python3 with rose can be found in the [UsingPython3 page of the ROS documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3).

#### ROS kinetic with python 3

Since at the time I started building my package the `franka_ros` wasn't released for melodic I had to use kinetic. However, since ROS kinetic does not fully support python3 getting the GQCNN to work under ubuntu 16.04 ROS Kinetic is not easy. I kept running into problem after problem. In the end, I decided to contribute python 2/python 3 compatibility fixed to the python 3 repositories and use python 2.7 instead. If other people need to work with python 3 and ROS kinetic, please refer to [this ROS issue](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/).

#### ROS melodic with python 3

As stated in the [distribution list ROS](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), ROS Python packages starting with Melodic are highly encouraged to support both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 or later. As a result, better ROS Melodic python 3 support is on its way. The core packages in ROS melodic are currently being ported from python 2 to python 3. If you experience a python 2/3 incompatibility issue, you can check the corresponding package repository at (https://github.com/ros)[https://github.com/ros] and file an issue. If you, have to use a package that is not yet ported to python 3 you have to build this package from source. As explained by [@gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/question/331628/message_filter-python-3-not-working-in-ros-melodic/), the procedure of doing this can be found [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/?answer=331009#post-id-331009).

#### Additional Resources

- [Write python 2 python 3 compatible code](https://wiki.ros.org/python_2_and_3_compatible_code).
- [Py2Py3 cheatcheat](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#catching-exceptions).

---

Originally posted by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) with karma: 111 on 2019-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0